How to use VSTACK with IF, AND, & NOT parameters?
I am working on a workbook where the 1st sheet uses VSTACK to reference multiple other sheets. The most important info here is that the ship by date is calculated based on the date of manufacture (DOM) + shelf life requirements for different vendors.
Current table:



Part #
DOM
Ship By




S12344
11/22/2024
7/25/2025


S12345
10/2/2024
6/4/2025


S12346




S12347
8/1/2024
4/3/2025


S12348
8/20/2024
4/22/2025


S12349
9/19/2024
6/2/2025



Ship By/Column E currently has the following formula, which works as intended:
=VSTACK(IF
          (NOT
              (ISBLANK(ATable1[DOM])),ATable1[DOM]+365,""),
               IF(NOT(ISBLANK(CTable1[DOM])),CTable1[DOM]+245,""),
               IF(NOT(ISBLANK(FTable1[DOM])),FTable1[DOM]+185,""),
               IF(NOT(ISBLANK(LTable1[DOM])),LTable1[DOM]+245,""),
               IF(NOT(ISBLANK(PTable1[DOM])),PTable1[DOM]+110,""),
               IF(NOT(ISBLANK(STable1[DOM])),STable1[DOM]+245,""))

I need to have something like this:
If part # = S12345, S12346, S12347, or S12348; AND DOM is not blank; then DOM+185
If part # =/ S12345, S12346, S12347, or S12348; AND DOM is not blank; then DOM+245
Desired table:



Part #
DOM
Ship By




S12344
11/22/2024
7/25/2025


S12345
10/2/2024
4/5/2025


S12346




S12347
8/1/2024
2/2/2025


S12348
8/20/2024
2/21/2025


S12349
9/19/2024
6/2/2025



I tried:
=VSTACK(IF
          (AND
              (NOT(ISBLANK(STable1[DOM])),
               STable1[Part Number]={"S12345", "S12346", "S12347", "S12348"}),
               STable1[DOM]+185,""))

Also tried:
=VSTACK(IF
          (AND
              (STable1[Part Number]={"S12345","S12346","S12347","S12348"},
               NOT(ISBLANK(STable1[DOM]))),
               STable1[DOM]+185,
               IF(AND
                     (NOT(STable1[Part Number]={"S12345","S12346","S12347","S12348"}),
                      NOT(ISBLANK(STable1[DOM]))),
          STable1[DOM]+245,"")))

Others as well, & swapped different parts around in them all to no avail.
None of them gave an error, simply result in False. They also do not give more than one value even though there are a total of 44 cells from STable1.

@Blackcat For all S parts, aside from S12345-S12348, the vendor requires 120 days of remaining shelf life (so 365-120=245 days after production where it can still be shipped). For S12345-S12348, the vendor requires 180 days of remaining shelf life (365-180=185).

The formula in cell D48
=IF(B48<>"",IF(OR(A48={"S12345","S12346","S12347","S12348"}),B48+185,B48+245),"")
The problem was that missing the logical sum evaluation of the result of the comparing. This is done by the OR function.

Adjust the row numbers to the actual table.
EDIT:
For table ranges the formula in C48
=IF(@[DOM]<>"",IF(OR(@[Part '#]={"S12345","S12346","S12347","S12348"}),@[DOM]+185,@[DOM]+245),"")


To be more specific, how could I do this if Part # on Sheet 1 is done by VSTACK, and DOM is on another sheet? I tried changing the values in your formula to match my setup, but it isn't working as desired.

To reference cells on different sheets use prefix of sheetnames like this:  Sheet1!A48:A53 and DOM!B48:B53 if the name  is DOM of the sheet. Microsoft

I need them to be dynamic ranges, I have been using the named table ranges i.e. STable1[DOM]. I tried =IF(STable1[DOM]<>"",IF(OR(STable1[Part #]={"S12345","S12346","S12347","S12348"}),STable1[DOM]+185,STable1[DOM]+245),"") but the result is true for all Part #s.

Need a @ sign for @STable1[Part '#]. Need the formula be placed in the first data row.

Adding the @ sign did not work either. The full formula looks like this: =VSTACK(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(ATable1[DOM])),ATable1[DOM]+365,""),IF(NOT(ISBLANK(CTable1[DOM])),CTable1[DOM]+245,""),IF(NOT(ISBLANK(FTable1[DOM])),FTable1[DOM]+185,""),IF(NOT(ISBLANK(LTable1[DOM])),LTable1[DOM]+245,""),IF(NOT(ISBLANK(PTable1[DOM])),PTable1[DOM]+110,""),IF(STable1[DOM]<>"",IF(OR(@STable1[Part #]={"S12345","S12346","S12347","S12348"}),STable1[DOM]+185,STable1[DOM]+245),""))

I added the formula for table in the answer. Pls. find the edit.
